# printing lines that contain 60 characters

Tags: python

I'm having trouble printing a string in lines chat contains 60 characters.

my code is below:

```
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrtsucwxyz'

for i in range(0, len(s), 60):
    for k in s[i:i+60]:
        print k
```

Comment: What is the significance of "60 characters"? Does it work with 59 characters, or is it irrelevant?

Comment: I'm using it to format biological data, so I need the lines printed in characters of 60

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s[i:i+60]` will slice the 60 characters you want into a string. By adding a second for loop, you're looping over each character in that string and outputting it separately. Just output `s[i:i+60]` instead

Comment: +1 for a clearer/beginner-friendly explanation, answering before me, and fixing the typo in my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Print the slice itself, not each character in the slice.

```
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrtsucwxyz'

for i in range(0, len(s), 60):
    print s[i:i+60]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [textwrap module](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap), ie `textwrap.fill(s, 60)`

Comment: +1: I didn't even know about the textwrap module. It is *much* slower though. Testing w/ timeit on 1000 iterations I got the following results: 400 chars- range: 0.83 textwrap: 3.24, 4000 chars- range: .83 ave textwrap: 244.09.