# In Biopython: Can you ‘print’ so a long output will be formatted as multiple lines each with a max char length, as often seen in the FASTA format?

Tags: formatting, biopython

I have been trying to take information from a genbank file, and print out just the locus tag and translation using the below code by xbello which I modified.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for rec in SeqIO.parse("file.gb", "genbank"):
    if rec.features:
       for feature in rec.features:
           if feature.type == "CDS" and feature.qualifiers.has_key('translation'):
               print '>'+feature.qualifiers['locus_tag'][0]
               print feature.qualifiers['translation'][0]
```

This works however it prints out each of the translation sequences as very long lines (I assume the maximum character length python allows),
I was wondering if it was possible to set it so that they would be formatted into multi-line paragraphs with about 60 characters a line, which is what you often seen in .faa files for example.

I have tried `print(textwrap.fill(feature.qualifiers['translation'], width=60))` and `print(textwrap.wrap(feature.qualifiers['translation'], width=60))`

So far that has not worked, I have tried doing 
`X = feature.qualifiers['translation']`
and doing `print(textwrap.fill(X, width=60))`

But unsurprisingly the computer had no idea what I was asking it to do… 
I am not sure what other format commands work with print instead of `Xout.write`, I have a strong feeling I have not written this in a way that lets the computer know I want it to wait for the text from `print feature.qualifiers['translation']` and then text wrap that with a width=60

I use cmd or powershell to run this code as a script, with ">X.xx" to give the output file name and file type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printing lines that contain 60 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145046/printing-lines-that-contain-60-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom print function which gets as input a string and splits the string into parts of 60 char and then prints those parts.

```
def custom_print(string):
    counter=0
    res=""
    for char in string:
        if counter==60:
            print res
            counter=0
            res=""
            continue
        res+=char
        counter+=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 

That is a great idea and worked perfectly.

Comment: The answer is correct but the implementation is inefficient. Slicing the string instead of creating a new one 60 times is simpler and faster. You could use `enumerate` to get rid of the counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian's solution will not work if the length of the sequence is less than 60. It will print nothing.

I'm adding another solution:

```
def fasta_pretty_print(seq):
    k = 60
    sixty_bp = [seq[i:i+k] for i in range(0, len(seq), k)]
    print('\n'.join(sixty_bp))
```